# Ember.merge does not trigger property change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm manipulating an array using Ember.merge. However, this does not seem to trigger a change in the template where I display something if the array is present. This seems to work when I use array.pushObjects. Just wondering if this is desired behavior. Related twiddle: 
https://ember-twiddle.com/9782f55c16c052851965055fd92c1bf9

Comment: Merge is meant to be used with 2 objects not 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `notifyPropertyChange` by `this.notifyPropertyChange('array1')`;

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.7.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/merge.js#L1

It looks they are not using any Observable methods like pushObject for merging so we should notifyProperty change manulally when you try merging.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm just wondering why this isn't the default behavior.

Comment: I dont know the reason behind scene but may be performance reason IMHO... Side note [in this guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) they are saying we cant use nested forms of `todos.@each.owner.name` or `todos.@each.owner.@each.name`..for this limitation they didn't mention the reason ...may be that this reason will be applicable to this problem too.